# Computation Involving Matrix Exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I am reading Serre's book *Complex Semisimple Lie Algebras*, and I have a problem about how to do a computation involving matrix exponential.

Let $V$ be a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. Let $X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $Y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $H = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$. It is easy to verify that $X,Y$ are nilpotent elements of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and thus the endomorphisms $X,Y$ of $V$ are nilpotent. So $e^X,e^{-Y}$ are just polynomials of $X,Y$, respectively. Now let $\theta = e^Xe^{-Y}e^X$, we want to verify that
\begin{equation}
\theta\circ X = -Y\circ \theta, \theta\circ Y = -X\circ \theta,\theta\circ H = -H\circ \theta.
\end{equation}
Since I am not familiar with matrix exponential, I find it hard, even in this case the matrix exponential is just a finite sum. One possible way is to use induction on the smallest integer $n$ such that $X^n = 0$ in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$. But it seems tedious. Is there any better way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$X^2=Y^2 =0,$$ so it follows, that the exponential series $$e^{a X} = \sum \frac{1}{k!} \ a ^k \ X^k = 1 + a X.$$ The matrix exponential  series converges in any vector norm in the same way as the real or complex series.

X,Y are not normal, so the series is the definition of $e^X.$

For diagonalizable matrices the exp coincides with the transform of the diagonal matrix of exp of the eigenvalues, simply by $$U^{-1} X^n U =(U^{-1} X U)^n,$$ the fact, that for normal matrices, thinking as being diagonal matrices, works for any kind of complex functions, as long as there are no zero eigenvalues in denominators.